# AS3 Preloader Eventlistener Strangeness

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, preloader, addeventlistener

I have a preloader that loads and attaches a swf like so:

```
stage.addChild(loadedSWF);
```

In the loadedSWF I have an eventlistener:

```
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, onKeyDown);
```

When a TextField added to the display list is focused the onKeyDown stops responding

**BUT**

When the loadedSWF is opened without the preloader the onKeyDown works while focus is on the TextField

**Why does this occur? How can this be controlled?**

Here is the preloader:

```
l.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, loop);
    l.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, done);
    l.load(new URLRequest("http://www.foo.com/foo.swf"));

    function loop(e:ProgressEvent):void
    {
        perc = Math.round(e.bytesLoaded / e.bytesTotal * 100);
        lt.text = String(perc);
        if (perc >= 100)
            l.contentLoaderInfo.removeEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, loop);
    }

    function done(e:Event):void
    {
        l.contentLoaderInfo.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, done);
        stage.addChild(l);
    }
```

Comment: Wouldn't the preloader then be of issue? You should probably post some code for it.

Comment: Added the preloader to the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was an Event Security issue, I had to pull out the AS3 Manual for this one, during the bubbling and capture phases events have security limitations. In my case the stage which belongs to the preloader was not safe for the loaded swf.

To fix this, add the following line to the swf being loaded

`Security.addDomain("http://www.yourdomain.com");`

I assume that this line is already in the preloader.

Also to check if a swf has access to the parent it is attached within the Loader class you can use

`l.contentLoader.childAllowsParent`

Answer (score 0):

put the instantiation of your keyboard event into an onAddedToStage event.

```
addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onAddedToStage);

function onAddedToStage(evt:Event):void
{
    removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onAddedToStage);
    stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, onKeyDown);
}
```

this will stop it from working in the stand alone swf, but it will work when loaded into its loader shell.

Comment: well poop.  that was my guess :)